# Reusing a Vue component

Tags: javascript, templates, vuejs3, vue-component

In my case I have a Vue App using Syncfusion as a template. I want to reuse some of the elements of a component into a second one. My question is: **How would I be able to reuse a component inside another component and exclude some of its elements?**

An example of what I am asking about would be

```html
<! -- Component A template-->
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="lastname">
<input type="number" id="age">
```

```html
<! -- Component B template -->
<input type="text" id="workplace">
<input type="email" id="email">
```

I want that the fields (elements) in component A be part of component B except the age input.
The above example is just a mere and simplified idea of what I am trying to do.
Beside this I'd want to do the same thing about the scripts, but exclude any script related to age input.
Any idea, learning resource suggestion or example would be appreciated!